# Execute SQL on Ignite cache of BinaryObjects

Tags: apache-spark, ignite

I am creating a cache of BinaryObject from spark a dataframe and then I want to perform SQL on that ignite cache.

Here is my code where `bank` is the dataframe which contains three fields (id,name and age):

```
    val ic = new IgniteContext(sc, () => new IgniteConfiguration()) 
    val cacheConfig = new CacheConfiguration[BinaryObject, BinaryObject]()
    cacheConfig.setName("test123")
    cacheConfig.setStoreKeepBinary(true)
    cacheConfig.setIndexedTypes(classOf[BinaryObject], classOf[BinaryObject])

    val qe = new QueryEntity()
    qe.setKeyType(TestKey)
    qe.setValueType(TestValue)
    val fields = new java.util.LinkedHashMap[String, String]()
    fields.put("id", "java.lang.Long")
    fields.put("name", "java.lang.String")
    fields.put("age", "java.lang.Int")
    qe.setFields(fields)
    val qes = new java.util.ArrayList[QueryEntity]()
    qes.add(qe)

    cacheConfig.setQueryEntities(qes)

    val cache = ic.fromCache[BinaryObject, BinaryObject](cacheConfig)

    cache.savePairs(bank.rdd, (row: Bank, iContext: IgniteContext) => {
        val keyBuilder = iContext.ignite().binary().builder("TestKey");
        keyBuilder.setField("id", row.id);
        val key = keyBuilder.build();

        val valueBuilder = iContext.ignite().binary().builder("TestValue");
        valueBuilder.setField("name", row.name);
        valueBuilder.setField("age", row.age);
        val value = valueBuilder.build();
        (key, value);        
    }, true)
```

Now I am trying to execute an SQL query like this:

```
cache.sql("select age from TestValue")
```

Which is failing with following exception:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "AGE" not found; SQL statement:
select age from TestValue [42122-191]
  at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
  at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
  at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
  at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.optimize(ExpressionColumn.java:147)
  at org.h2.command.dml.Select.prepare(Select.java:852)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of field `age` is incorrect, it should be the following:

```
fields.put("age", "java.lang.Integer")
```